# SFTP Chroot Jail preventing SSH: This service allows sftp connections only

Tags: ssh, sftp

I set up a SFTP Chroot Jail succesfully, but would like to give my users access over SSH, in addition to SFTP. If I attempt to SSH in with the testuser, after providing the password, putty closes. Using Python's `paramiko` module to perform an SSH connection, I receive this message:

```
This service allows sftp connections only.
```

The usual culprit to this problem appears to occur when the sysadmin leaves `ForceCommand internal-sftp` uncommented in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file. However, my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` looks like this, with `ForceCommand internal-sftp` commented out:

```
Match group jailedusers
    ChrootDirectory /jailed/%u
    #ForceCommand internal-sftp
    AllowTcpForwarding no
```

When I created my testuser, I initially set his bash to `/bin/false`, but have changed it to `/bin/bash`. If I cat `/etc/passwd` and search for my testuser, I see:

```
testuser:x:573:502::/jailed/testuser:/bin/bash
```

What other reason could be preventing me from SSHing with this user?

Comment: What do you see in syslog?  Are you getting any denies in /var/log/audit/audit.log or dmesg?  Did you try setting the sshd_config loglevel to debug and restarting sshd?  Did you remove testuser from the jailedusers group, given that it wont be able to use bash in a chroot.

Comment: You don't have bash in chroot.